# How to upload multiple JSON files into CouchDB

Tags: json, couchdb

I am new to CouchDB. I need to get 60 or more JSON files in a minute from a server.
I have to upload these JSON files to CouchDB individually as soon as I receive them.
I installed CouchDB on my Linux machine.
I hope some one can help me with my requirement.
If possible can someone help me with pseudo code.

#### My Idea:

1. Is to write a  python script for uploading all JSON files to CouchDB.
2. Each and every JSON file must be each document and the data present in 
   JSON must be inserted same into CouchDB
   (the specified format with values in a file).

#### Note:

These JSON files are Transactional, every second 1 file is generated
so I need to read the file upload as same format into CouchDB on 
successful uploading archive the file into local system of different folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use CouchDB bulk API, even though you have specified that you need to send them to db one by one. For example, by implementing a simple queue that gets sent out every say 5 - 10 seconds via a bulk doc call will greatly increase performance of your application.

There is obviously a quirk in that and that is you need to know the IDs of the docs that you want to get from the DB. But for the PUTs it is perfect. *(it is not entirely true, you can get ranges of docs using bulk operation if the IDs you are using for your docs can be sorted nicely).*

From my experience working with CouchDB, I have a hunch that you are dealing with Transactional documents in order to compile them into some sort of sum result and act on that data accordingly (maybe creating next transactional doc in series). For that you can rely on CouchDB by using 'reduce' functions on the views you create. It takes a little practice to get reduce function working properly and is highly dependent on what it is you actually what to achieve and what data you are prepared to emit by the view so I can't really provide you with more detail on that.

So in the end the app logic would go something like that:

```
get _design/someDesign/_view/yourReducedView
calculate new transaction
add transaction to queue

onTimeout
   send all in transaction queue
```

*If I got that first part of why you are using transactional docs wrong all that would really change is the part where you getting those transactional docs in my app logic.*

Also, before writing your own 'reduce' function, have a look at [buil-in ones](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions) (they are alot faster then anything outside of db engine can do)

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API

EDIT:
Since you are starting, I strongly recommend to have a look at [CouchDB Definitive Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/tour.html).

**NOTE FOR LATER:**

Here is one hidden stone (well maybe not so much a hidden stone but not an obvious thing to look out for for the new-comer in any case). When you write reduce function make sure that it does not produce too much output for the query without boundaries. This will extremely slow down the entire view even when you provide reduce=false when getting stuff from it.

Comment: Why not use the new docs instead of the "old" wiki? http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/bulk-api.html?highlight=bulk#post--db-_bulk_docs

Answer (score 1):

### python program to parse the json and insert into CouchDb:

```
import sys
import glob
import errno,time,os
import couchdb,simplejson
import json
from pprint import pprint

couch = couchdb.Server() # Assuming localhost:5984
#couch.resource.credentials = (USERNAME, PASSWORD)
# If your CouchDB server is running elsewhere, set it up like this:
couch = couchdb.Server('http://localhost:5984/')

db = couch['mydb']


path = 'C:/Users/Desktop/CouchDB_Python/Json_files/*.json'
#dirPath = 'C:/Users/VijayKumar/Desktop/CouchDB_Python'   
files = glob.glob(path)
for file1 in files: 
    #dirs = os.listdir( dirPath )
    file2 = glob.glob(file1)

    for name in file2: # 'file' is a builtin type, 'name' is a less-ambiguous variable name.
        try:
            with open(name) as f: # No need to specify 'r': this is the default.
                #sys.stdout.write(f.read())
                json_data=f
                data = json.load(json_data)
                db.save(data)
                pprint(data)
                json_data.close()
                #time.sleep(2)
        except IOError as exc:
                if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR: # Do not fail if a directory is found, just ignore it.
                    raise # Propagate other kinds of IOError.
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to get JSON documents from a server and send them to CouchDB as you receive them. A Python script would work fine. Here is some pseudo-code:

```
loop (until no more docs)
    get new JSON doc from server
    send JSON doc to CouchDB
end loop
```

In Python, you could use [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) to send the documents to CouchDB and probably to get the documents from the server as well (if it is using an HTTP API).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your Answer.Here I have written a code w.r.t your  idea please help me whether it is correct or not

Comment: I have posted my answer please reply me with any mistakes. As you may find that i have not followed coding standards please bare with me.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout the `pycouchdb` module for python3. I've used it myself to upload lots of JSON objects into couchdb instance. My project does pretty much the same as you describe so you can take a look at my project [**Pyro at Github**](https://github.com/mnmnc/pyro) for details.

My class looks like that:

```
class MyCouch:
""" COMMUNICATES WITH COUCHDB SERVER """

  def __init__(self, server, port, user, password, database):
    # ESTABLISHING CONNECTION
    self.server = pycouchdb.Server("http://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + server + ":" + port + "/")
    self.db = self.server.database(database)

  def check_doc_rev(self, doc_id):
    # CHECKS REVISION OF SUPPLIED DOCUMENT
    try:
        rev = self.db.get(doc_id)
        return rev["_rev"]
    except Exception as inst:
        return -1

  def update(self, all_computers):
    # UPDATES DATABASE WITH JSON STRING
    try:
        result = self.db.save_bulk( all_computers, transaction=False )
        sys.stdout.write( " Updating database" )
        sys.stdout.flush()
        return result
    except Exception as ex:
        sys.stdout.write( "Updating database" )
        sys.stdout.write( "Exception: " )
        print( ex )
        sys.stdout.flush()

        return None
```

Let me know in case of any questions - I will be more than glad to help if you will find some of my code usable.